# How to get multiple checkbox values in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

I'm trying to get values from all selected checkboxes and store them in useState. I was able to get value of the selected row in a table, but I can't store multiple selected values in state. My code is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Jane",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "James",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: "40"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Alexa",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: "27"
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      name: "Jane",
      lastName: "Brown",
      age: "40"
    }
  ];

  const [peopleInfo, setPeopleInfo] = useState([
    {
      id: "",
      first: "",
      last: "",
      age: ""
    }
  ]);

  console.log(peopleInfo);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tr>
          {data.map((item) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={item.id}
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  width: "150px"
                }}
              >
                <input
                  onChange={() => {
                    setPeopleInfo({
                      id: item.id,
                      first: item.first,
                      last: item.last,
                      age: item.age
                    });
                  }}
                  value={peopleInfo}
                  style={{ margin: "20px" }}
                  type="checkbox"
                />
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.name}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.lastName}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.age}</td>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-austin-zv70s?file=/src/App.js:24-1639)

I'm able to get id, name, last name and age values of the selected row, but when I select new checkbox previous row's info gets updated with the new one. I can't seem to figure out how to store all values from multiple selected checkboxes. Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your state updater grabs data that doesn't exist for the first and last name properties. You mutate the state shape from array to object. It's also not clear what you want the checkbox's onChange handler to do? Can you explain in more & clearer detail what you want the desired behavior to be?

Comment: @Drew Reese, hi. I would like to grab values( name, last Name, age) for each selected row and store them in state.  For example, if user selects checkboxes of the 1st& 2nd row, in my state I should have                    {  
      id: "1",
      name: "Jane",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "James",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: "40"
    },

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's ok to have an array containing your selected people.

```js
const [peopleInfo, setPeopleInfo] = useState([]);
```

what you want to do is using `e.target.checked` value to modify the array above.

```js
<input
  onChange={(e) => {
    // add to list
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setPeopleInfo([
        ...peopleInfo,
        {
          id: item.id,
          first: item.name,
          last: item.lastName,
          age: item.age,
        },
      ]);
    } else {
      // remove from list
      setPeopleInfo(
        peopleInfo.filter((people) => people.id !== item.id),
      );
    }
  }}
  value={peopleInfo}
  style={{ margin: '20px' }}
  type="checkbox"
/>
```

And the results can be accessed from `peopleInfo`.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest storing your selected item objects in an object using the `item.id` as a key. This will provide you constant-time (`O(1)`) value lookups, versus linear-time (`O(n)`) using an array. If/when you need an array of the checked values you access via `Object.values(peopleInfo)`.

```
const [peopleInfo, setPeopleInfo] = useState({});
```

And use a functional state update to copy all previous state into a new object and update the value associated with the specific item's `id`. Make sure to use the checkbox input's `checked` prop instead of the `value` prop.

```
<input
  onChange={() => {
    setPeopleInfo((state) => ({
      ...state, // <-- shallow copy previous state
      [item.id]: state[item.id] // <-- update value by id
        ? null
        : {
        id: item.id,
        first: item.name, // <-- use name property
        last: item.lastName, // <-- use lastName property
        age: item.age
      }
    }));
  }}
  checked={peopleInfo[item.id]} // <-- use checked prop, retrieve value by id
  style={{ margin: "20px" }}
  type="checkbox"
/>
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-multiple-checkbox-values-in-react-js]

Full Code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [peopleInfo, setPeopleInfo] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(peopleInfo);
  }, [peopleInfo]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tr>
          {data.map((item) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={item.id}
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  width: "150px"
                }}
              >
                <input
                  onChange={() => {
                    setPeopleInfo((state) => ({
                      ...state,
                      [item.id]: {
                        id: item.id,
                        first: item.name,
                        last: item.lastName,
                        age: item.age
                      }
                    }));
                  }}
                  value={peopleInfo[item.id]}
                  style={{ margin: "20px" }}
                  type="checkbox"
                />
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.name}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.lastName}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.age}</td>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Callback Optimization

Factor out the `onChange` callback logic into a function that consumes the `item` you want to toggle the checkbox state of. I suggest using [curried functions](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983) so you enclose the callback value and can avoid the unnecessary anonymous callback.

```
const toggleHandler = (item) => () => {
  setPeopleInfo((state) => ({
    ...state,
    [item.id]: state[item.id]
      ? null
      : {
          id: item.id,
          first: item.name,
          last: item.lastName,
          age: item.age
        }
  }));
};

...

<input
  onChange={toggleHandler(item)} // <-- pass item to handler
  checked={peopleInfo[item.id]}
  style={{ margin: "20px" }}
  type="checkbox"
/>
```

Comment: Definitely the idea I had, except I would not allow creating as many handlers as there are checkboxes. If you have the peopleInfo indexed by `id` I would make the handler generic and dynamically retrieve the proper peopleInfo using the checkbox value instead.

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest changing `hallow` to `shallow` copy, it will make it easier to find proper literature on this should the OP need it

Comment: @daformat Sure, I do that normally as well, but didn't feel it relevant enough to the question/issue, but definitely good advice.

Comment: No worries, perfectly understandable, as long as we're giving a heads up about being cautious on this it should be fine.

Comment: Well this was fast, thanks for adding it, this answer is definitely the one I would pick

Comment: No, there was only one place in the first code block, which you fixed (editing one char is prevented here, it was my intent to fix it for you)

Answer (score 1):

You can create peopleInfo state as a empty array:

```
const [peopleInfo, setPeopleInfo] = useState([]);
```

then in your onChange function of your checkbox handle the object array:

```
onChange={() => {
   handleChange(item);             
}}

const handleChange = (item) => {
   let tempPeopleInfo = peopleInfo;
   //here we look if your checked item is allready in your array. if so, remove with filter.
   if (tempPeopleInfo.some((people) => people.id === item.id)) {
     tempPeopleInfo = tempPeopleInfo.filter((people) => people.id !== item.id);
   } else {
     tempPeopleInfo.push(item);
   }
   setPeopleInfo(tempPeopleInfo);
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-lederberg-hk6cd?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

One of nice approach, try this. We can manage easily based on checked true/false. While send BE also we can filter it out by checked.

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  
  const [peopleInfos, setPeopleInfo] = useState([
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Jane",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: "25",
      checked:false
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "James",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: "40",
      checked:false
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Alexa",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: "27",
      checked:false
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      name: "Jane",
      lastName: "Brown",
      age: "40",
      checked:false
    }
  ]);
  const peopleChecked=(event)=>{
    setPeopleInfo(peopleInfos.map((info)=>{
     return {...info, checked:event.target.checked};
    }));

   // or
   
    // const people = [...peopleInfos];
    // people[index] = {...people[index], checked:event.target.checked};
    // setPeopleInfo([...people]);
  }
  

  console.log(peopleInfos);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tr>
          {peopleInfos.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={item.id}
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  width: "150px"
                }}
              >
                <input
                  onChange={(event)=>peopleChecked(event, index)}
                  name="people"
                  value={item.checked}
                  style={{ margin: "20px" }}
                  type="checkbox"
                />
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.name}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.lastName}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{item.age}</td>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Beware, `info.checked = !info.checked;` is state mutation!

Comment: It seems pretty inefficient to map through the entire array each time just to update one value, am I missing something?